Product of square of eigenvalues is no more than products of 2-norm of the columns
I want to show for a square matrix $\mathbf A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ (not necessarily distinct)
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|^2 \leq \prod_{i=1}^n\|\mathbf a_i\|^2_2,
$$
where $\mathbf a_i$ is the $i$-th column of $\mathbf A$.
My attempt is considering the QR decomposition for non-singular $\mathbf A$, so that $\mathbf A=\mathbf Q\mathbf R$ with unitary $\mathbf Q$ and upper triangular $\mathbf R$ with $r_{ii}\geq 0$. I think the product in the equation is from $\text{det}(\mathbf A^H\mathbf A)=\text{det}(\mathbf R^H\mathbf Q^{H}\mathbf Q\mathbf R)=\text{det}(\mathbf R^H\mathbf R)$.
But I don't know how to get the $\prod_{i=1}^n\|\mathbf a_i\|^2_2$ term. Any help is appreciated.

Consider $|\det A|^2$ instead of $\det(A^HA)$.

You are in the right direction. This is the Hadamard's inequality. Its proof is written in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right 4th edition.

@user1551 and Duong Ngo, Thanks for your comments! Both solve my problem.
